# I want rotate animation imageview on android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation

i want to animate imageview on android, i want to achieve like below animation, please let me guide if any one have idea how to achieve this animation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Single Image animation ( motion / vibration )**

Example:
Under res folder,

Step1 : create a new folder called "anim" to store your animation resources and put this on that folder.( name animation.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="100"
android:fromDegrees="-15"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:toDegrees="15" />
```

Step 2. And the method for animate the imageview

```
public void AnimateBell() {
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.animation);
    ImageView imgBell= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBell);
    imgBell.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_notifications_active_white_48dp);
    imgBell.setAnimation(shake);
}
```

**2. If you want animate with multiple image you can try as follows**

Have you considered using Frame Animations? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Frame

You can specify an xml in your anim folder that contains a frame-by-frame animation, specifing each image duration, and other settings, check it out

```
eAnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1), 100);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2), 500);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image3), 300);
animation.setOneShot(false);

ImageView imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

// start the animation!
animation.start()
```